# Prove the isomorphism of Z-modules

Tags: linear-algebra

I've read in many books, that $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z \times\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z\cong \Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z$

and $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z ⊗ \Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z\cong 0$ .

How can I prove the isomorphism of them?

For  $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z ⊗ \Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z\cong 0$,

I let B: $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z \times\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z \to A $ , a bilinear form

and $3B(a,b)=B(3a,b)=B(0,b)=0;
$

and $5B(a,b)=B(a,5b)=B(a,0)=0.$ Is it right? How can I prove the first one?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you mean $\mathbb Z / 3\mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb Z / 5 \mathbb Z \cong 0$ (this sign is \otimes in latex), since $\mathbb Z / 3\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z / 5 \mathbb Z$ is the same as $\mathbb Z / 3\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 5 \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @lisyarus no, they are not the same

Comment: What makes you think they aren't? Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Direct_sum_of_abelian_groups

Comment: @lisyarus sorry my mistake, is't tensor product for the second one

Answer (score 3):

The second isomorphism is a special case of the more general isomorphism,  valid in any commutative ring $R$ and any $R$-module $M$:

> For any ideal $I$ in the commutative ring and any $R$-module $M$,
>   $$ R/I\otimes_R M\simeq M\otimes_R R/I\simeq M/IM. $$

As a consequence, if $I$ and $J$ are two ideals in $R$, we obtain
$$ R/I\otimes_R R/J\simeq (R/J)\Bigm/I\,(R/J)\simeq (R/J)\Bigm/(I+J/J)\simeq R/(I+J)$$
by the  *3rd isomorphism theorem*.

Now in a P.I.D.,, if $I=(a)$, $J=(b)$, we know that by definition, $(a)+(b)=(\gcd(a,b)).$

Comment: thanks a lot. And what about the first isomorphism?

Answer (score 2):

For the second isomorphism, one can consider any elementary tensor $x\otimes y$ in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. Then, $3$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ namely $2*3=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, we have $$x\otimes y=x\otimes (3\times(2y))=3(x\otimes(2y))=(3x)\otimes(2y)=0\otimes (2y)=0$$
using only computational properties of the tensor product. Because the space $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by elementary tensors, and these are all zero, we deduce that $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}=0$.

For the first isomorphism, I invite you to check the Chinese remainder theorem if you don't already know about it. It exactly states what you want. Click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) for the Wikipedia page.